# WPF/C# Insert data into databa

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, dataadapter, sqldataadapter

I'm really new to C#/WPF. I try to program my first app. So I added a local database (.mdf file) with a DataSet and TableAdapter. I also created a table (User).

```
public static int CreateNewId()
        {
            using (var todoDataSet = new ToDoDataSet())
            {
                using (var tableAdapter = new UserTableAdapter())
                {
                    var userid = (int) tableAdapter.GetLastId();
                    userid = userid + 1;
                    return userid;
                }
            }
        }
```

With this function I get the last Id of my table – this works fine. But if I want to insert some new data into the table it doesn't. There isn't any error message, but the new data won't show in the table.

```
public static void CreateUser(User user)
        {

            using (var todoDataSet = new ToDoDataSet())
            {
                using (var userTableAdapter = new UserTableAdapter())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        userTableAdapter.Insert(user.ID, user.Loginname, user.Firstname, user.Lastname, user.Email, user.Password, user.PicUri);
                        userTableAdapter.Update(todoDataSet.User);
                        MessageBox.Show("Update successful");
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Does someone know what I did wrong? Or is something missing?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:
Code for calling CreateUser():

```
private void RegisterUser(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int userId = Mysql.CreateNewId();
            Console.WriteLine(rm.FirstName);
            User loggedUser = new User(userId, rm.Loginname, rm.Email, rm.FirstName, rm.LastName, rm.Password);
            Console.WriteLine(loggedUser.ID);
            Console.WriteLine(loggedUser.Loginname);
            Mysql.CreateUser(loggedUser);
        }
```

Comment: What is your insert statement in UserTableAdapter

Comment: @daniel.shih I use the official Insert method of the tableAdapter. So I didn't add an extra insert statement.

Comment: Could you show the code,where call the method  
public static void CreateUser(User user),and Assign user object

Comment: @daniel.shih I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may call a method `todoDataSet.User.Add[tablename]Row` DataTable Add mehtod instead of
`userTableAdapter.Insert(user.ID, user.Loginname, user.Firstname, user.Lastname, user.Email, user.Password, user.PicUri);`

then you call  `userTableAdapter.Update(todoDataSet.User);`,You will save data in DB.

Because the method `userTableAdapter.Update` is from `DbDataAdapter`